# system io file not found exception/ error handling

Tags: c#

I'm working in C# and I try to do a program that get some infoes the files in a Directory. I made it but i have a problem with the error Handling. When the program runs and for example I give just random numbers to list file infoes i get this error message:

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: "'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Temp\first_project\first_project\bin\Debug\12345'.'"

Please someone help me to do the error handling.

Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
    using System.IO;
    class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Please :");
                string hely = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] __file = Directory.GetFiles(hely);
                string[] __dir = Directory.GetDirectories(hely);

                foreach (string i in __file)
                {
                    FileInfo fajl = new FileInfo(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", fajl.Name, fajl.Extension, fajl.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                }
                foreach (string i in __dir)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo _file = new DirectoryInfo(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", _file.Name, _file.Extension, _file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                }


            Console.ReadKey();
             }

        }
```

Comment: Well we don't know what you want to *do* if the directory the user provides doesn't exist. Basically, you should catch `FileNotFoundException` and do whatever you want that way, but we can't really help you without a clearer indication of what you're trying to achieve, or what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You should check existence of a path with

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory)
```

and of a file with

```
System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)
```

Then, you need to take the try-catch block inside the for-loop, to catch any possible exceptions that occur because of insufficient rights/permissions.

e.g.

```
foreach (string i in __file)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo fajl = new FileInfo(i);
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", fajl.Name, fajl.Extension, fajl.LastWriteTime.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

}
```

You could also create two try-catch blocks - depends on what you want to do.

```
try
{
    foreach (string i in __file)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo fajl = new FileInfo(i);
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", fajl.Name, fajl.Extension, fajl.LastWriteTime.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

    }
}
catch (System.Exception exLoop)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(exLoop.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Note that in your example, you should first check if the directory "hely" exists:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(hely))
{
    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Directory \"{0}\" does not exist.", hely);
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
    // or: return;
}
```

Since exception handling is usually very slow, I would however recommend that you check for the existence of the file/directory explicitly. It would also be a good idea to do so for the file/directory-listing & read-access rights for the respective user. But even if you do so, keep the try-catch, because there might be cases where your program suddenly fails - e.g. when a removable storage is forcefully removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch

```
using System;
    using System.IO;
    class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Please :");
                string hely = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                   string[] __file = Directory.GetFiles(hely);
                   string[] __dir = Directory.GetDirectories(hely);
                   foreach (string i in __file)
                   {
                      FileInfo fajl = new FileInfo(i);
                       Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", fajl.Name, fajl.Extension, fajl.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                   }

                   foreach (string i in __dir)
                   {
                      DirectoryInfo _file = new DirectoryInfo(i);
                      Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", _file.Name, _file.Extension, _file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                   }
                }
                catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
             }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the [file exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (string i in __file)
{
    if (File.Exists(i))
    {
        FileInfo fajl = new FileInfo(i);
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", fajl.Name, fajl.Extension, fajl.LastWriteTime.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RTFM?

Read [Directory.GetFiles method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

It says that you will get the `DirectoryNotfound` exception if the specified path is not found. Obviously folder 'C:\Temp\first_project\first_project\bin\Debug\12345' does not exist.

Proper code would be:

```
string hely = ...
try
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(hely);
    ProcessFiles(files);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

If you don't know how to react on exceptions read [MSDN about exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/index)